# What is the best way to handle exception in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, controller-advice

I am developing an application in Spring Boot. I was wondering what is the best way to handle exceptions. So following is my code,

`ExceptionHandler.java`
I am using `@ControllerAdvice`. What is the best to use? `@ControllerAdvice` or `@RestControllerAdvice`?

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(NotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> notFound(NotFoundException notFoundException) {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, notFoundException.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse>(errorResponse, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

And implemented service layer `@Service` as follows,

```
@Override
public User update(User newUser) throws NotFoundException {
    Optional<User> user = userRepository.findById(newUser.getId());

    if (!user.isPresent()) throw new NotFoundException("Record Not Found!");

    return userRepository.save(newUser);
}
```

In `Controller.java` code is as follows,

```
@PutMapping
public User update(@RequestBody User user) {
    User updatedUser = userService.update(user);

    if (updatedUser == null) throw new SomeOtherException("Exception while Updating!");
    
    return updatedUser;
}
```

So my questions are:

Is the above approach bad? Is it okay to throw exceptions in the service layer and will it catch automatically by `@controlleradvice`? Or need to throw only in the controller? I am seeking the best practice to handle exceptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you used is perfectly fine.

As **@ControllerAdvice/@RestControllerAdvice** is used to handle exceptions globally throughout the controllers [flow].

You can throw exceptions in @Service layel also. [That is the same thing]
ControllerAdvice will catch it.

You can customize your Exceptions your own way.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I also like your approach. Maybe you want to have a look at Lombok and @SneakyThrows, too: I find it unneccessary to have throws XYZ on the methods, when at the end you handle them globally anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Don't throw an exception at Controller layer instead throw an exception at service layer. Implement the Controller advice so whenever exception throws from the service layer so it will execute controller advice code and send response to the API.

Need to construct proper error message with error code in the Controller Advice, it should be readable and understandable to the user.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(NotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> notFound(NotFoundException notFoundException) {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, notFoundException.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse>(errorResponse, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

Controller code,

```
@PutMapping
public ResponseEntity<UserDto> update(@RequestBody UserDto user) {
    UserDto userDto = userService.updatedUser(user);
    return new ResponseEntity<UserDto>(userDto, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Service layer code,

```
@Override
public User update(User newUser) throws NotFoundException {
    Optional<User> user = userRepository.findById(newUser.getId());

    if (!user.isPresent()) throw new NotFoundException("Record Not Found!");

    return userRepository.save(newUser);
}
```